Nextjs returning 404 for all chunks and css from time to time
My app is running Nextjs 14.2.4 and I'm currently using both the pages and app routers. From time to time (mostly seems to be when I push a commit to Git), the app starts returning 404s for all chunks and CSS. 
To get things working again I have to terminate the server and start it again.
Has anyone experienced this before and found a fix?
